# Node: cannot parse a JSON via API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I load a JSON from file as a string, try to parse it back to JSON and send as a response:

```
router.get('/todos', (req,res) =>{
    let todos = fs.readFile('todos.json', 'utf8',(err, data) =>{
        if (err) throw err

        res.send(JSON.parse(todos)) 
    })
})
```

my todos.json file:

```
{
    "todos": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "task number 1",
            "priority": 3,
            "done": false
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "task number 2",
            "priority": 3,
            "done": false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "task number 3",
            "priority": 3,
            "done": false
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "text": "task number 4",
            "priority": 3,
            "done": false
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "text": "task number 5",
            "priority": 3,
            "done": false
        }
    ]
}
```

However I get this error:

> undefined ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at fs.readFile (/Users/mgonline/Desktop/programs/assessment/node-todo/routes/api/v1/todo.js:11:17)
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

I don't know why but when I console.log this string fetched from file it seems like my program change it a bit by adding a commma after last object in array of collections:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "text": "task number 5",
    "priority": 3,
    "done": false
},
```

Which supposedly rise this error. Should I rewrite my JSON different way in order to avoid collisions?

Comment: Try `res.send(JSON.parse(data))` instead of `res.send(JSON.parse(todos))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

You are using [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) incorrectly.  `fs.readFile` will return `undefined` because `readFile` is asynchronous.  The contents of the file actually arrive in the `data` parameter of the callback that you provided.

### To Fix

Remove `let todos =` entirely and just call `fs.readFile` (because you don't need the return value of `fs.readFile`).

Then call `JSON.parse(data)` instead of `JSON.parse(todos)` (because that's where your file's contents arrive).

#### Before

```
router.get('/todos', (req,res) =>{
    let todos = fs.readFile('todos.json', 'utf8',(err, data) =>{
        if (err) throw err

        res.send(JSON.parse(todos)) 
    })
})
```

#### After

```
router.get('/todos', (req,res) =>{
    fs.readFile('todos.json', 'utf8',(err, data) =>{
        if (err) throw err

        res.send(JSON.parse(data)) 
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess,The editor automatically adds a comma when saving.  try to change the setting of IDE to removing the comma from the array element when the json file is saved

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `todos` in your application, it is ***undefined*** hence you are getting error as,

As corrected by @Sebastian Kaczmarek, `todos` is holding return value of `fs.readFile`. As `fs.readFile` returns `"undefined"`, you are getting error.

Use `data` which is the name of the argument in your script which holds the content of the `required` file.

```js
router.get('/todos', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('todos.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    res.send(JSON.parse(data));
  })
})
```

Comment: Actually, he did define `todos`. He wrote `let todos = fs.readFile(...)` so it is defined but it's value is `undefined`. If it wasn't defined he would get `ReferenceError`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek- Oops! My bad, I will edit it. I totally missed that. Thanks!